# php form with radio buttons

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to get the following form to work. I want to be able to send the information from the text fields and radio buttons via email when the user submits the form. I also want the page to redirect to a 'thankyou' page after the form submits. As it currently stands, the page redirects but no email is sent. Here is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
  Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
  Date: <input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
  Job description: <input type="text" id="job" name="job" />

    <label for="yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="q1" value="Yes"/>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="No" name="q1" value="No"/>

    <label for="yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="q2" value="Yes"/>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="No" name="q2" value="No"/>

    <label for="yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="q3" value="Yes"/>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    <input type="radio" id="No" name="q3" value="No"/>
    <input type="radio" id="Maybe" name="q3" value="Maybe"/>
    <label for="why">Why? (please state)</label><input type="text" id="why" name="why"/>

    <input type="submit" id="message_submit" class="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$toaddress = "example@example.com"; 
$subject = "Subject"; 
$email = "sender@example.com"; 
$url = 'thankyou.php'; 

$msg = "$name\n"; 
$msg.= "$date\n"; 
$msg.= "$job\n"; 
$msg.= "$q1\n"; 
$msg.= "$q2\n"; 
$msg.= "$q3\n";
$msg.= "$why\n"; 

$mailheaders = "From: $email\n"; 
$mailheaders .= "To: recipient@example.com\n"; 
$mailheaders .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; \n"; 

mail($toaddress, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders); 

if($sent)
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

Comment: what's going wrong with this code? any error or warning?

Comment: `id`s have to be *unique* per document.

Comment: Apologies, updated my answer to include the outcome of the submit form action!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use **$_POST[ ]** to retrieve your data from html form... if your using POST method then change your code like this...

```
$msg = $_POST['name']; 
$msg.= $_POST['date'];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't create global variables for every form input you submit. Use the [`$_POST` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hope all values are retrieved and no syntax errors at all. 
If you are testing it offline or localhost then it might not work by simply php mail function, so in that case u can use smtp mail server which will work if there is an internet connection.

check this out : [PHP Mail server classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9/post/1-Sending-email-using-SMTP-servers-of-Gmail-Hotmail-or-Yahoo-with-PHP.html)